# Async Task in ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to implement a logic which gets the data from the database Async.

Can anyone guide me how can I implement ASync Task in ASP.NET, C#. I want to start that task in Global.asax (Application_Start) so I can fetch my data from the cache which is stored Async.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out the following links

[Executing Asynchronous Tasks in ASP.NET](http://aspalliance.com/1778_Executing_Asynchronous_Tasks_in_ASPNET.all)

[Performing Asynchronous Work, or Tasks, in ASP.NET Applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx)